# How can I use typist.js in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a typewriter effect in WordPress.
So I searched with google and I tried it.
Following the code below,

```
$path = __DIR__;
    wp_enqueue_script( 'typed_js', $path . '/js/define_typed.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'typed_js', $path . '/js/typed.min.js', array('jquery') );
```

And I defined the define_type.js like this.

```
var typed = new Typed('#type', {
    strings: ['Change <b>!deas</b>', 'Create WordPress <b>Themes</b>', 'Create WordPress <b>Plugins</b>', 'Do Lots Of <b>Stuff</b>'],
    typeSpeed: 100,
    backSpeed: 100,
    backDelay: 1000,
    startDelay: 1000,
    loop: true,
    });
```

And then I used 'type' to make some effect.

```
<h2>We <span id="type"></span></h2>
```

But it doesn't work.
Thanks for any opinions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Where did you put this code? You say you tried it, but don't tell us how you implemented it. The first code block has an error with the `'typedJS`. That should be unique for each script. Are the scripts saved to your theme directory? We need more information to help.

Comment: I referred "https://websiteguider.com/how-to-create-a-typewriter-effect-in-wordpress/". And also I didn't insert this code to in theme directory, I added this to wp-include/js.

Comment: `wp-include/js` is the wrong place to put any of this code. You never want to add code to core. Do you have a child theme? What theme are you using?

Comment: Ah, I used truelove theme. @disinfor, would you please send me examples.

Comment: You need to follow this guide in creating a child theme: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/ It's pretty easy to follow. Once you do that, it'll be easier to help on your specific issue.

Comment: @disinfor, I solved this issue using TypingEffect PlugIn on Wordpress. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

A few things to do/check:

1. Give the scripts you're including have unique handles. In your example, they match. That's not allowed.
2. Make sure scripts are loaded in the correct order. For example, `define_typed.js` will depend on the Typed source code being loaded. `wp_enqueue_script` has a mechanism for doing that.
3. Make sure these scripts are being loaded *after* the DOM elements are rendered (in the footer). Otherwise, your JavaScript won't have any elements to target. Again, `wp_enqueue_script` lets you do that via parameters.

After doing these things, your enqueued code would look a little more like this:

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'typed_js_source', $path . '/js/typed.min.js', array(), null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'typed_js_setup', $path . '/js/define_typed.js', array('typed_js_source'), null, true );
} );
```

I have not tested this, but it should send you in the right direction. For more information, you can dig into the `wp_enqueue_script` documentation:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: This question is almost a year old and OP already solved it with a plugin. There is no need for an answer on this.

Comment: @disinfor

1. I felt like it. 

2. Solving it with a plugin doesn't provide context as to why the original scenario wasn't working to begin with. If other people run into similar issues and want to understand what the source of the problem is, it's nice to have better context.

Comment: Fair enough, but you might want to test it if you're going to provide the answer - since it's actually testable. For your #3 point, you might want to explain what that parameter is, or at least in this answer explain what the parameters you can pass to `wp_enqueue_script`. I know the Codex explains it, but better to have it in the answer itself.

Comment: Since you are so weirdly passionate about StackOverflow discourse, I will appease you and update my answer and my earliest convenience. Maybe a year from now.

Comment: HA! I just find half answers not helpful, that is all. If you do update this in a year, I applaud you for it.